# How to determine if vectors are generators of a vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

How can I determine if vectors $\vec{v}$ of 
$B=\left \{\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix} \right \} $ are generators of the vector space $Mat(2,2;\mathbb{K})$?

Comment: In this case it is easy.  Three vectors cannot generate a $4$-dimenisional space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\dim\mathbb K^{2\times2}=2\times2=4$ and you only have $3$ vectors, they cannot span the whole space.

Answer (score 1):

The space $\text{Mat}_{2,2}$ is four dimensional, that is, its basis has four vectors. A set of $n$ vectors can only generate a space of $m$ dimensions if $n \geq m$. You have three vectors, so it cannot generate the whole space.